# Plotting a continuous of time data in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot the distribution of turtle nesting activity over a night using ggplot, but I want to exclude the times from 8am - 6pm. Also, I need the x-axis to start at 7pm and end at 7am.

[image]

My code is

```
ggplot(sub.1) + geom_bar(aes(x = sub.1$time)) + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 23), breaks = seq(0, 23, 1)) + xlab("Hour") +  ylab ("Frequency")
```

Any assistance would really be appreciated.

Comment: For anyone to give you a specific answer, you'll need to provide the data you are working with so we can get you an answer that matches the structure of that data. That is, please provide the results of `dput(sub.1)`. That said, generally, you'll want to filter `sub.1` to get just the nightly data, and store `sub.1$time` in a proper date-time format to get the ordering you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I'll post some comments in there when I get a chance. Hope it helps!

```
# Example Data
SampleHours <- sample(1:23, 3000, replace = TRUE)

# Keep wanted Hours
IncludedHours <- c(19:23, 1:7)
Index <- SampleHours %in% IncludedHours

# Create dataframe
sub.1 <- data.frame(Hour = SampleHours[Index])

# Change the factor levels
sub.1$Hour <- as.factor(sub.1$Hour)

FactorLevels <- c(19:23, 1:7)

levels(sub.1$Hour) <- FactorLevels

# Plot

library(ggplot2)


ggplot(sub.1) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = sub.1$Hour)) + 
  xlab("Hour") +  
  ylab ("Frequency")
```

**EDIT**

Changed a part to identify which hours to keep, not which ones to exclude. I think it makes it easier to follow

Answer (score 1):

My approach used `dplyr`. First, I generated some fake data:

```
times = sample(seq(0,23), 10000, replace=T)
nest = sample(c(0,1), 10000, replace=T)
data = data.frame(times, nest)
```

Then, I used `dplyr` to pipe the results:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% filter(times>18 | times<8) %>%
  transform(times=factor(times, levels=c(19:23,0:7))) %>%
  ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=times)) +
  xlab("Hour") +
  ylab ("Frequency")
```

The `filter` call selects the hours; the `transform` serves to do the same as @William did to create the order 19-7.